# Write Hostnames of VMs in Array (VMs are in a Cluster/ Hyper-V)

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm trying to get an array including the hostnames of all VMs in the cluster.

I'm getting a chicken-egg-problem because I need the computername:

```
Invoke-Command -computername -scriptblock{...}
```

`Get-Item` isn't working either because the Hyper-V is running in a Cluster:

```
(Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters").GetValue("HostName")
```

At this point I'm not sure if it is possible at all?

Comment: Get the name from get-vm and map that with the invoke-command. That will do your work . You do not need to dig in registry for that.

Answer (score 0):

untested idea:

```
Foreach($VM in $(Get-VM -ComputerName "HV01","HV02" | where state -eq 'Running')) {
    $VMId = $VM.Id
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $VM.ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Command -VMId $using:VMId -ScriptBlock { hostname }}
}
```